# How to detect EOF when reading a file with readline() in Python?

Tags: python, file, exception, readline, eof

I need to read the file line by line with `readline()` and cannot easily change that. Roughly it is:

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as i_file:
    while True:
        line = i_file.readline()
        # I need to check that EOF has not been reached, so that readline() really returned something
```

The real logic is more involved, so I can't read the file at once with `readlines()` or write something like `for line in i_file:`.

Is there a way to check `readline()` for EOF? Does it throw an exception maybe?

It was very hard to find the answer on the internet because the documentation search redirects to something non-relevant (a tutorial rather than the reference, or GNU readline), and the noise on the internet is mostly about `readlines()` function.

The solution should work in Python 3.6+.

Comment: It returns an empty string at EOF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> `f.readline()` reads a single line from the file; a newline character (`\n`) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This makes the return value unambiguous; if `f.readline()` returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached, while a blank line is represented by `'\n'`, a string containing only a single newline.

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as i_file:
    while True:
        line = i_file.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        # do something with line
```

Comment: That documentation is a tutorial, not a reference, but if it says what you quoted, then it is also fine.

Answer (score 4):

Using [this](https://web.physics.utah.edu/%7Edetar/lessons/python/fileio_formatting/node11.html) I suggest:

```
fp = open("input")
while True:
     nstr = fp.readline()
     if len(nstr) == 0:
         break # or raise an exception if you want
     # do stuff using nstr
```

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) mentioned in the comments, readline "returns an empty string at EOF".

Answer (score 3):

Empty strings returned in case of EOF evaluate to `False`, so this could be a nice use case for the walrus operator (in Python 3.8+):

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as i_file:
    while line := i_file.readline():
        # do something with line
```

Comment: AFAIK, walrus operator is only available in Python 3.8+.

Comment: @SergeRogatch good point